# Performant way to compare two array of objects with v8 & filter/find

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, v8

I have 2(well, > 2) arrays of objects with the structure like this:

```
const mainArr = [
  { article: "somename-1", price: 10, found: [] },
  { article: "somename-2", price: 20, found: [] },...
];
const toCompareArr = [
  { article: "somename-1", articleFormatted: "0somename-1", price: 20 },
  { article: "somename-3", articleFormatted: "0somename-3", price: 20 },...
];
```

And for **mainArr** i try to find all occurencies in 2nd **toCompareArr** array (basically - I need to create price comparator for different suppliers), like this:

```
let i = 0;
let j = 0;
const iMax = mainArr.length;
const jMax = toCompareArr.length;
for (; i < iMax; i++) {
  for (; j < jMax; j++) {
    if (
      mainArr[i].article === toCompareArr[j].article ||
      mainArr[i].article === `00-${toCompareArr[j].articleFormatted}`
    ) {
      mainArr[i].found.push(toCompareArr[j]);
    }
  }

  j = 0;
}

// also tried like this (for + for seems to be more speedy):
/*
let found;
for (; i < iMax; i++) {
  found = toCompareArr.filter(
    item =>
      item.article === mainArr[i].article ||
      item.articleFormatted === mainArr[i].article
  );

  if (found) {
    mainArr[i].found.push(found);
  }
}
*/
```

as **result** I want to get:

```
[
  {
    article: "somename-1",
    price: 10,
    found: [
      { article: "somename-1", articleFormatted: "0somename-1", price: 20 }
    ]
  },
  { article: "somename-2", price: 20, found: [] }
];
```

but it's extremely slow when I have **a lot of data** (normally there would be around 80k-100k array items in each)

And I stuck... Maybe there is a way to improve performance of filter & find here? I'm using latest Node & V8 features. Now it took around 5min to compare, if it would be 50% (let's say 2min - it's way better)

maybe somehow I should totally reinvent my logic? use some algorithms (would like to know - which one)

Comment: please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: btw, `mainArr[i].found` is never defined.

Comment: "*80k-100k array items*" - uh, are you trying to implement an in-memory database with node.js?

Comment: The basic approach is to make some sort of *index* so that you can perform fast lookups by name instead of 100,000 exhaustive searches of another similarly-sized array.

Comment: @Bergi no, not really :) data is parsed from spreadsheets... any suggestions here? like use mongo/sqlite etc?

Comment: don't think I can do any kind of index in js @Pointy

Comment: Of course you can. You can use a plain object since the names are simple strings.

Comment: @brabertaser19 Yes, especially if you have multiple tables that you need to join like this, I'd recommend sqlite or similar

Answer (score 4):

> It's extremely slow when I have a lot of data - normally there would be around 80k-100k array items in each

Use a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) for this task. A good DBMS should be able to do this comparsion is less than a second, using a [hash join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_join) or similar technique. Of course you can re-implement that in node.js if you insist - use the article identifier as the key in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 4):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const
    mainArr = [{ article: "somename-1", price: 10, found: [] }, { article: "somename-2", price: 20, found: [] }],
    toCompareArr = [{ article: "somename-1", articleFormatted: "0somename-1", price: 20 }, { article: "somename-3", articleFormatted: "0somename-3", price: 20 }],
    map = mainArr.reduce((m, o) => m.set(o.article, o), new Map);

for (let item of toCompareArr) {
    let object = map.get(item.article) || map.get('00-' + item.articleFormatted);
    if (!object) continue;
    object.found.push(item);
}

console.log(mainArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: To add some background explanation why this helps: the problem with the original approach is that the two nested for-loops have "quadratic" total run time: for arrays of length `n`, you'll have `n` outer iterations times `n` inner iterations. `n^2` grows quickly when your arrays are large. The `Map` technique avoids this: after building the Map (which is one loop, hidden inside `mainArr.reduce` in this case), you only need to iterate `toCompareArr` once.

Comment: by the way, would it be possible somehow to tune above code to compare with LIKE? for example: mainArr has item with article 'somePartNR' and toCompareArr has 'somePartNRwithSomeAdditional'... in sql I can just use article %, but how to be here with a map?

Comment: it depends where the comparison should happen. do you have a practical example?

Comment: like: `const mainArr = [
  { article: "0500", price: 10, found: [] },
  { article: "0600", price: 20, found: [] },...
];
const toCompareArr = [
  { article: "500A", articleFormatted: "0500A", price: 20 },
  { article: "600A", articleFormatted: "0500A", price: 20 },...
];`

Comment: so should be something like `let object = map.get(item.article) || map.get(item.articleFormatted) || map.get.startsWith(item.article));`

slicing end of the article - isn't the solution :)

Comment: the last one is not possible, because `map` as all other hashing methods need a key, not a (string) function. maybe you could find a way to use only a part of the string (depending of the structure).